# trying to use typescript library into javascript express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to use typescript library like [this](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)to a existing express nodejs application. but its not working. when i import the library functions its gives errors like Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined.

I am compiling the ts files to js files as well. Is there any other way to use typescript to existing node js application?

here is error stack

```
"stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined\n    at MetadataStorage.getAncestors (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/metadata/MetadataStorage.js:199:73)\n    at MetadataStorage.getMetadata (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/metadata/MetadataStorage.js:146:36)\n    at MetadataStorage.getExposedMetadatas (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/metadata/MetadataStorage.js:91:21)\n    at MetadataStorage.getExposedProperties (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/metadata/MetadataStorage.js:97:21)\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.getKeys (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/TransformOperationExecutor.js:328:70)\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/TransformOperationExecutor.js:110:29)\n    at ClassTransformer.plainToClass (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/ClassTransformer.js:17:25)\n    at plainToClass (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/class-transformer/index.js:20:29)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/build/src/api/controllers/source.controller.js:67:22)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at /Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/build/src/api/controllers/source.controller.js:7:71\n    at new Promise (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:2393:11)\n    at __awaiter (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/build/src/api/controllers/source.controller.js:3:12)\n    at exports.create (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/build/src/api/controllers/source.controller.js:58:38)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)\n    at /Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/build/src/api/controllers/auth.controller.js:12:13\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)\n    at Route.dispatch (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at /Users/saurabhkumar/platform/rest-api-service/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22"
```

Comment: Would have been helpful if there was actually new lines, not one big line...

Comment: Check out `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev` if you want to use typescript on your express app.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the typescript from here and forward but don't care to stick with already written js files, you can just leave it as js files...

Make sure you tsconfig is configured with `allowJs: true` or just run tsc with this option.

Check out allowJs option, first of all compiler options: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options